# confused on CSS3 on how to display text

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi, first off this is my codepen
http://codepen.io/willc86/pen/unjzG

Pretty much what I am trying to do is flip each image and reveal a "link" about me, email me, location, ect. just trying to learn it for fun. I've been trying to find a resource online, but its either too advanced where I do not understand what they are doing, or the code is not complete.

Was wondering if someone can show me a sample or a resource on a flipping image that will reveal text or is it that I need JS?

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the link below for Working Examples With Demos

[Hover Effect to Display Text](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/02/original-hover-effects-with-css3/)

[Working Example](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/)

```
.view {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
margin: 10px;
float: left;
border: 10px solid #fff;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
cursor: default;
background: #fff url(../images/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center
}
.view .mask, .view .content {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
top: 0;
left: 0
}
.view img {
display: block;
position: relative
}
.view h2 {
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
font-size: 17px;
padding: 10px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
margin: 20px 0 0 0
}
.view p {
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 12px;
position: relative;
color: #fff;
padding: 10px 20px 20px;
text-align: center
}
.view a.info {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 7px 14px;
background: #000;
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000
}
.view a.info:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey, that's an awesome effect